# ios - NSURLSession with dataTaskWithRequest fires only when app launch, not while the app is not running

Tags: ios, voip, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

As described in the title, I can reply as a text when remote notification comes. My http request works well if I tap the home button one time, but does not work when the app is not running, it waits. When the app is launched it works too.

```
// Please work
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    print(userInfo["personB"])
    if identifier == "comment-reply" {
        if let response = responseInfo[UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey],
            responseText = response as? String {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://example.com/post-ios.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let p = "a=123&b=\(responseText)"
            request.HTTPBody = p.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

now, am i need:
-VoIP certificate,
-background session configuration,
-dispatch something,
or
-upload task?

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE** for upload task

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    let id = userInfo["personB"]!
    if identifier == "comment-reply" {
        if let response = responseInfo[UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey],
            responseText = response as? String {
            let conf = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("replyPost")
            let requ = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://example.com/post-ios.php")!)
                requ.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let data = "a=123&b=\(responseText)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession(configuration: conf, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()).uploadTaskWithRequest(requ, fromData: data!)
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

It does not works too. Am i add additional handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call completionHandler() your application will be suspended again. This will happen before your task completes.

Instead of `uploadTask(with:from:)` you should call `uploadTask(with:from:completionHandler:)` and put `completionHandler()` in the completion handler block.

Comment: You quite right. and we do not need the background session configuration, default configuration is enough for it, because when we reply with the action app state already turn to running. Thanks :)